# SASS, COMPASS, SUSY - What is the relation?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I am using SUSY Grid with SASS and Compass, however if I am honest, I still don't understand why should I use Compass?

I mean I code my CSS styles with SASS and compile them with CodeKit in CSS files.
As a grid system I use SUSY grid.

But why should I install and use Compass?

What is the relation between Compass and Susy grid?

Comment: Did you *look* at what Compass offers?  If you don't need those features, don't use it.  Simple.  It shouldn't be possible to use Susy *without* Compass because multiple files depend on it.

Comment: "Responsive grids for Compass." ... not much more to say I guess.

Answer (score 9):

### What Compass is

There's indeed a lot of ambiguity about what Compass is. I've made a kinda non-canonical attempt to resolve it, please read it and then resume from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17317098/901944 .

### What Susy is and why it needs Compass

Susy is one of Compass extensions.

With Compass, you simply require Susy from your `config.rb` and voila! You can use Susy in your SASS code by simply doing `@import susy` (and compiling your SASS with Compass).

Without Compass, you'll have to download Susy manually, add it to your project files and provide a path to include it, something like `@import ../vendor/susy/sass/susy'. This will most likely work for Susy but will probably fail for some other Compass extensions because this method does not enable their custom SASS functions written in Ruby (i haven't tested it though because it makes no sense). Also, dragging the sources of dependencies together with the source of your project is generally considered to be poor practice.

### PS: Singularity is better than Susy (in my humble opinion)

In due time, Susy introduced me the world of responsive web design and i owe a debt of gratitude to Susy and its creator, <strike>the well-known CSS guru Eric Meyer</strike> [Eric M. Suzanne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930386/eric-m-suzanne).

But in fact, Susy is currently not the best grid framework available. I consider [Singularity](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity) to be most advanced and flexible. I also find Singularity simpler to understand and to use than Susy (though both require a fair amount of effort to be learned). Eric is working on a modern version of his framework, called Susy Next. It is yet to be released and i think it will not overpower Singularity. So i suggest you start learning Singularity instead of good old Susy.

Singularity also works great in conjunction with another Compass extension: [Breakpoint](http://breakpoint-sass.com/) (and its sidekick [Breakpoint Slicer](https://github.com/lolmaus/breakpoint-slicer)) that is used to set media queries (i. e. make responsive websites).

Singularity has great support here on StackOverflow.com. If you exhaust all sources of information and still struggle to implement something with Singularity, don't hesitate to file a question tagged with [`singularitygs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singularitygs).