# Installing Sass on PC with no command line knowledge

Tags: css, ruby, command-line, sass

I'm going through the [Sass tutorial](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html) and am stuck at this part:

> Once you have Ruby installed, you can install Sass by running
>
> ```
> gem install sass
> ```

So I opened up command prompt and typed in

```
gem install sass
```

Just like it said. It doesn't work though. I get this message back:

```
'gem' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have almost no knowledge of command line but wish to use Sass. Can someone please walk me through what I'm doing wrong?

Yes I did searches for tutorials for people who don't know command line. I only came up with a Mac guide, which does me no good since I'm on Windows 8, and a program that my company has blocked access to.

Comment: Nevermind. Apparently on the installer I needed to have "Add Ruby executables to your PATH" checked. Would have been nice if they had mentioned that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just means the gem executable is not in your %path%. You can either run the ruby installer again and select the check box during the install for "Include ruby in path" (or some similar message) or just add the path (something like C:\Ruby200) to your system %path% variable.

Comment: Thanks! I found the solution on my own a few minutes before your answer popped up, but checking that "Add Ruby executables to your PATH" box on the installer is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ruby Installer for Windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/) to install Ruby. After that you'll be able to do `gem install sass`.

Also, i recommend you get familiar with Compass as soon as possible. Compass is a very ambiguous thing for newcomers, so here's an explaination for you: [Import common modules by default when compiling SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315450/import-common-modules-by-default-when-compiling-scss/17317098#17317098)

And here's a great source of information for SASS newbies: https://github.com/Snugug/training-glossary/wiki

Comment: Yes like I said I tried 'gem install sass' but it was not working. I found out a few minutes ago I needed "Add Ruby executables to your PATH" checked. After that it worked fine. Thanks.

Comment: RubyInstaller.org does that for you.